# What is the equivalent in metal of glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)?

Tags: objective-c, metal, metalkit

What is the equivalent in metal of `glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)?` The Stencil Test is a per-sample operation performed after the Fragment Shader. The fragment's stencil value is tested against the value in the current stencil buffer; if the test fails, the fragment is culled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a depth-stencil state object created from a descriptor whose `frontFaceStencil` and/or `backFaceStencil` are set to descriptors with a `stencilCompareFunction` other than `MTLCompareFunctionAlways`.